# Process many incoming emails in Rails: MySQL vs. Imap / Pop3 vs. other solution

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, performance, email, parsing

at an application I'm working on users can forward their email-accounts to an address from our system (something like email@userid.amazingstuff.com ). It doesn't matter here why they should do this, but I need some professional advice on the best way to approach this.

The basic idea is that our mailserver receives the incoming (forwarded) mails and a mailpoller (which runs in a loop) downloads the mails from the mailserver, processes them (get the text, assigns them to an account, etc.) and saves them via an "IncomingMail" ActiveRecord Model.

But I'm not sure how the poller should connect the server? Via Imap / Pop? Or should I store the mails on the mailserver with MySQL and connect to the DB directly? Or is this a bad idea?

I need a fast, reliable and scaleable system.

Thanks for your advice!

---

**Update**
I think a DB like MySQL is always faster than parsing a file system. It should also be easily scaleable. I'm no thinking about using DBMail (http://www.dbmail.org/). Has anyone any experience using this solution? Or any further hints / comments?

Thanks!

Comment: How was your experience with DBmail? I intend to use it in one of my projects.

Answer (score 0):

Pop should work, check out some example code here:
http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/pop/rdoc/classes/Net/POP3.html